# A tree that combines horizontal and vertical layouts

Tags: d3.js, tree

I'm trying to create a D3 tree that consists of both horizontal and vertical orientations. I want the first and second levels of the tree to be horizontal and then each following level to be vertical under its parent. Here is the result I got so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/z3UX6/17/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
},
width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
        return d.depth < 2 ? [d.x, d.y] : [d.y, d.x];
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


root = {
    "name": "Homepage",
        "children": [{
        "name": "test1",
            "children": [{
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "test2",
            "children": [{
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "test3",
            "children": [{
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "test4",
            "children": [{
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }, {
            "name": "page",
        }]
    }]
};
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        if (d.depth < 2) {
            d.y = d.depth * 100
        }
        else {
            d.y = d.parent.x;
        }
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function (d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
        .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return d.depth < 2 ? "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")" : "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function (d) {
        return d.target.id;
    });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
        };
        return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
        });
    });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
        };
        return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
        });
    })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}

</script>
```

As you could see the 3rd level is not actually positioned under the parent, although I managed to put it in the same "column" as a parent, but the vertical level is not correct. Also links are all gone crazy. This I can't figure out at all.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if you can do this with a single tree layout. I would try to combine several, i.e. one for the initial horizontal orientation and then one each for the following vertical ones. This would require you to split the data as well though.

Comment: Interesting approach. Thanks. I'll give it a try.